# PRG Pattern in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post-redirect-get

I'm new to ASP.Net MVC. In PHP, I always use the PRG pattern even when the post request was invalid. It was pretty easy with session flashes (also user friendly).

In ASP.Net MVC, however, I don't see an easy way to do PRG when the request is invalid. I could think of some ways, but I don't think they are good practices and put some extra unnecessary work.

Moreover, from a couple of articles that I've read, a PRG when the request was invalid was discouraged. If it's a bad practice, then what's the better way to handle unsuccessful post requests? Is it really better off without the PRG? And should I just let the rather annoying browser warnings when a user tries to refresh the page?

Comment: The normal practice is to return the view is `ModelState` is invalid so that validation error messages are displayed.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I understand. But is the POST request hanging fine or acceptable? I mean, when you refresh, with all the browser warnings?

Comment: Yes, that is a bit of a pain. I have seen some attempts to follow the PRG pattern and still maintain `ModelState` such as in [this blog](http://www.jefclaes.be/2012/06/persisting-model-state-when-using-prg.html) (but don't use `TempData` - if you refresh its lost unless you use `.keep()` or `.peek()`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke We're using a very similar solution as the one given in the blog (I don't see much pain there in, by the way), but I don't see what alternative to `TempData` could be used (without making things really painful) : you loose your invalid ModelState when refreshing, indeed, but that's less pain then refresh problems without PRG pattern, dont' you think ?

Comment: TempData is out because it's only alive for one request and it's shared between "tabs". That makes the session dangerous as well. Stateless servers are a good goal to achieve. When you let the client repost the data you easily achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

In Mvc, it's normal practice to handle your Post Actions as it follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public virtual ActionResult LoginForm(LoginViewModel loginViewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
        return View("Login", loginViewModel);

    return Redirect("/");
}
```

As you can see, the property ModelState.IsValid will tell you if the request is invalid, therefore giving you the ability to return the same view and display the error messages in the ValidationSummary when the Post request contains an error. This is the code for the View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LoginForm", "Account"}))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary() // THIS WILL SHOW THE ERROR MESSAGES
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)
        @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password)
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    }
```

Comment: How does that work if you have multiple forms on the same page?  You need to submit them to different actions, otherwise ASP.NET can't distinguish which form was submitted.

Comment: Of course, different forms are posted to different actions. Each action will be ready to accept a strongly typed model specific for the logic of the form.

Comment: But the point is, you were saying in your answer that you had to POST back to the same URL to maintain the ModelState.  That means you can't post to different actions, or you lose the ModelState - the URL changes, or you have to do a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

We have been using PRG pattern in our asp.net mvc web apps for about 5 years.  The main reason we adopted PRG was to support browser navigation (eg back, forward).  Our web apps are used by customer and for front/back office operations.  Our typical web page flow is starts with a login, then progresses via many list/detail view.  We also incorporate partial views which also have their own viewmodel.  List views will have links (GETS) for navigation.  Detail views will have forms (POSTS) for navigation.

**Keys aspects of our PRG:**

1. We incorporate viewmodels so each view has a viewmodel (all data access is done in the viewmodel).
2. Each viewmodel has a set() & get() method to maintain the key data field values associated with the most recent instance of the view.  The set/get values are persisted in sessionstate.
3. The set method has a parameter for each value that needs to be set.  The get method is just called from the viewmodel constructor to populate the viewmodel's public "key" values.
4. The viewmodel will also have a public load() method that get all neccessary data for its view.

**Our PRG pattern overview:**

1. In controllers we have a separate GET method and a POST method for each action.  The GET only displays a view; the POST processes the posted data.
2. For list (menu) views, the controller GET method calls the target view's set('item key values here') method, then invokes a RedirectToAction to to the target view's controller GET action.
3. The controller GET method will instantiate the viewmodel (thus causing get of set values), call its load method which uses the set/get key values to get it data, and returns the view/viewmodel.
4. The controller POST method will either have the viewmodel save the valid posted data then redirect to the next desired page (probably the previous list menu) -OR- if redisplay the current view if the data is invalid.
5. I have not documented all the PRG flow senarios that we implemented, but the above is the basic flow.

**SAMPLE VIEWMODEL SET/GET METHODS**

```
private void GetKeys() {
  Hashtable viewModelKeys;
  if (SdsuSessionState.Exists("RosterDetail"))
  {
    viewModelKeys   = (Hashtable)SdsuSessionState.Get("RosterDetail");
    EventId         = (int)viewModelKeys["EventId"];
    SessionNo       = (int)viewModelKeys["SessionNo"];
    viewModelKeys   = null;
  }
}
public static void SetKeys(int eventId, int sessionNo) {
  Hashtable viewModelKeys = new Hashtable();
  viewModelKeys.Add("EventId",eventId);
  viewModelKeys.Add("SessionNo",sessionNo);
  SdsuSessionState.Set("RosterDetail",viewModelKeys);
  viewModelKeys = null;
}
```

**SAMPLE CONTROLLER**

```
[AcceptVerbs("Get")]

public ActionResult MenuLink(int eventId, int sessionNo, string submitButton) {
  if (submitButton == RosterMenu.Button.PrintPreview) {
    // P-R-G: set called viewmodel keys.
    RosterDetail.SetKeys(eventId,sessionNo);
    // Display page.
    return RedirectToAction("Detail","Roster");
  }
  if (submitButton == RosterMenu.Button.Export) { etc ...}
}
```